# How to avoid Electron application auto update?

Tags: electron, electron-react-boilerplate

How to avoid Electron app auto update?
My Electron application recently acts so weird. When I closed the application the icon on desktop disappear and few minutes later it show again but it becomes the electron-react-boilerplate template on my desktop. I figured out that my electron application auto updated and make my original application gone.
I google how do avoid auto update but nothing I can find either in electron official website or other website.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you open main.ts you can find AppUpdater and comment above it about auto-updates. But I don't think that is what happened to you.